# Use multiple or single virtual directory for enterprise application

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I want to ask a question about IIS hosted Wcf Services.
Our projects has 44 modules and each module have about 40 wcf services.
And my question is which way can i follow.

1 - I can create virtual directories for each modules.
2 - I can create one virtual directory.

If i choose first way.I have to manage many configs and assemblies.
And it's difficult to use cache, authentication and authorization data.

We use seperate wcf application projects for each module now.
So I can merge all applications to one virtual directory with post build events by copying svc files and assemblies to root bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have many shared things, like the same authentication, static variables, the same bindings, the same common dll's, etc., and they are built from the same source code (so you don't want to separately update modules), then use one application.

Comment: Yes you're right.
But is there any solution for using common assemlies or config sections with one instance for multiple virtual directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can host in seperate virtual directory with svc file in it, the dll will be shared accross multple virtual directories